# Android warning - Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init> ref from Android.Support.V7

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, logcat, opcode

I'm not sure where this error is generating from. My application works fine and I've not come across any crashing; however I receive the below in my LogCat.

My application uses an ActionBar and ListView. Anyone come across this before?

EDIT: Seems to be only happening when running on Android 2.x

Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams., referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView$LayoutParams.

VFY: unable to resolve direct method 8309: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;. (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V

VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000

VFY: dead code 0x0003-0007 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuView$LayoutParams;. (Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuView$LayoutParams;)V

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like  those classes are missing from your apk. Make sure to include the necessary Jars into your Apk (sounds like the support library).

Also in relation to this error, this is due to the Class Loader trying to resolve the reference in your code to actual operation codes (opcode) that the OS can recognize.

Comment: In my Build.Gradle I use MavenCentral dependencies. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2+'

Would this not fetch all the required?

Answer (score -1):

I had somewhat a similar issue. But later I found that I was trying to call a menu which does not exist.